# How to show radius and ratio of area to circumference for circles?

Tags: javascript, math

How to show radius and ratio of area to circumference for circles with radius of 4 and continuing while the ratio is less than 10?

Comment: Use simple maths and a pie constant in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Circumference = 2*pi*r

Area = pi*r^2

ratio Area : Circumference = r/2

So you have to iterate from 4 to 19 or 20.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ratio = (pi*r^2)/(2*pi*r) = r/2
// let x and y define the center coordinate
var circles = [{x:0,y:0,r:5},{x:10,y:10,r:17},{x:20,y:20,r:31}];
circles = circles.filter(function(k){ return k.r/2 < 10});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the ratio of area to circumfence till the ratio is less than 10, starting from radius 4.

try this code

```
var ratio = 0;
var radius = 4;
while(ratio < 10 )
{
  var area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
  var circumfence = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  var ratio = area/circumfence;
  document.body.innerHTML += "Ratio of area to circumfence for radius " + radius + " is " + ratio );
  radius++;
}
```

Comment: my goodness thank you. yep, pretty much. i made an error when it came to the output. still new to this stuff